# Socket.io and MEAN.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, mean.io

I'm trying to do communication between front angularjs and backend node  through socket.io. application is built over Mean.io boiler plate. Socket is unable to connect to backend.
Here is my code

Angular.js

```
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('localhost:3000');
    console.log('-------->' , socket)

    socket.emit('new', { data: 'asd' });
    socket.on('hi',  function (data) {
        alert('socket connected     hi called');
        console.log('===================== ============== data',data);
    });
    socket.on('broadcast',  function (data) {
        console.log('===================== ============== data',data);
    });



</script>
```

Node.js

```
MeanStarter.register(function (app, users, system, database, http) {
   var io = require('./server/config/socketio')(http);
   io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log(chalk.orange('------------------------ > a user connected'));
   socket.emit('hi', { data: 'hello' });    
   socket.on('new', function (data) {
      console.log(chalk.orange('=======> hello'));
      })
    });
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/server/views'))
  MeanStarter.routes(app, database);
  MeanStarter.angularDependencies(['mean.system', 'mean.users', 
  'ui.bootstrap','ngFileUpload', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect', 
  'angularMoment','mwl.calendar'])
  return MeanStarter
 })
```

./server/config/socketio

```
  'use strict';
    var config = require('meanio').loadConfig(),
     cookie = require('cookie'),
     cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
     socketio = require('socket.io'),
     chalk = require('chalk');
     module.exports = function(http) {   
     var io = socketio.listen(http);
    //  console.log( chalk.green('Socket Io conf',io));
     io.use(function(socket, next) {
        var data = socket.request;
        if (!data.headers.cookie) {
            return next(new Error('No cookie transmitted.'));
        }
        var parsedCookie = cookie.parse(data.headers.cookie);
        var sessionID = parsedCookie[config.sessionName];
        var parsedSessionID = 
              cookieParser.signedCookie(parsedCookie[config.sessionName], 
              config.sessionSecret);
        if (sessionID === parsedSessionID) {
            return next(new Error('Cookie is invalid.'));
        }
       console.log( chalk.green('Socket Io conf'));
        next();
      });

    return io;
    };
```

And here is my browser response  [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9GcB.png)

Comment: please upload the full code. did you check if server listens on 3000

Comment: have uploaded  ./server/config/socketio code too. projects runs on port 3000, everything works fine except sockets